# Format output of jasmin with ANTLR in java

Tags: java, format, antlr, space, jasmin

```
int addr = gen_address();
              $code.addr = addr;
              $code.append(
                  ldc(44),
                  istore(addr),
                  "getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;",
                iload(addr),
                "invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/print(I)V");
int addr = gen_address();
              $code.addr = addr;
              $code.append(
                  ldc(22),
                  istore(addr),
                  "getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;",
                iload(addr),
                "invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/print(I)V");
```

This grammar will output a number `44` and `22`
But the output will be look like this ( `4422` )

I want to add a space between the numbers so the output would be ( 44 22 )

I think something needs to be changed in the

```
            "invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/print(I)V");
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not easy to understand: Your code seam to be ANTLR action code, right? Your compiler generates a jasmin (java assembler) file, right? And you later execute this file and you expect to see (`44 22`)?

So if you examine the jasmin code you find that you never printed out a space.

**One Option:**
change `invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/print(I)V` to `invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/print(Ljava/lang/String)V;` Yet you will have to prepare the arguments for this step, 22 is an integer and you have to convert it to " 22" which is a lot of jasmin code.

**A better Option (from my point of view):**
insert `invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/print(C)V` between the two statements. You have to push ' ' (space char) on the stack before you invoke.